# Animate each array element Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, animation

I have converted  meteorolog json data into array and display in table form. It works and it display. But, I have problem with wind direction. The wind direction should be displayed as animation instead of numerical number. Wind speed and wind direction should be displayed in one single table cell. I manged to display in a single cell. I wanna convert wind direction to  animation, like fade in or out. But, i have out of idea how to add animation to each array element.

```
function createTable(){
      var table = document.getElementById("wData"); /*  */
      var days = convertToDay();  /*days where Metrology data collected */
      var windS = returnWSpeed()  /*speed of wind */
      var average = returnAveargeTempreatur(); /* average tempreature*/
      var max = returnMaxTempreture();  /* maximum tempreture*/
      var wd = returnWD();  /* wind direction*/
      for(i = 0 ; i < 10;  ++i){
       var row = table.insertRow(i); 
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        cell1.id = 'cell' + 0; 
        cell1.style.border = '1px solid black';
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell2.id = 'cell' + 1; 
        cell2.style.border = '1px solid black';
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        cell3.id = 'cell' + 2; 
        cell3.style.border = '1px solid black';
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        cell4.id = 'cell' + 3; 
        cell4.style.border = '1px solid black';
        cell4.style.height ='80px'
        cell1.innerHTML  = days[i]; 
        cell2.innerHTML  = max[i]; 
        cell3.innerHTML  =  average[i]; 
        cell4.innerHTML  = wd[i] + "<br />" + windS[i];/*animate wd[i]*/
      }

  }
```

Comment: Can you create a working fiddle please http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: the way you are doing it `wd[i]` ends up being a static html text... you can create a container for it and then animate the container like: `cell4.innerHTML  = "<div class='animWD'>" +  wd[i] + "</div>" + "<br />" + windS[i];` then animate all elements of class animWD, `$(".animWD").fadeToggle( "slow", "linear" );` [fadeToggle](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/)

Comment: Here with mocked data, https://jsfiddle.net/dj3tx4hf/4/

Comment: @DIEGO CARRASCAL,  is div class dynamic ?

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea...

HTML:

```
 <table id="tab101">
 <tr>
 <th>Day</th>
 <th>Maximum temperature</th>
 <th>Average temperature</th>
 <th>Wind direction</th>
 </tr>
 <tbody id="wData"></tbody>
 </table>
```

CSS:

```
th,tr{
    border: 1px solid black;   
    height: 50px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: left;


}
```

JS:

```
 function createTable(){
      var table = document.getElementById("wData"); /*  */
      var days = ['M', 'T', 'W', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'Sun', 'M', 'T', 'w']; 
      var windS = [6,7,4,4,5,1,8,9,10,11]  /*speed of wind */
      var average = [10,12,5,6,7,5,10,8,9,10]; /* average wind*/
      var max = [8,12,13,20,9,15,15,31,18,20];  /* maximum tempreture*/
      var wd = [200,210,250,201,301, 209,159,317,218,202];  /* wind direction*/
      for(i = 0 ; i < 10;  ++i){
       var row = table.insertRow(i); 
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        cell1.id = 'cell' + 0; 
        cell1.style.border = '1px solid black';
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell2.id = 'cell' + 1; 
        cell2.style.border = '1px solid black';
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        cell3.id = 'cell' + 2; 
        cell3.style.border = '1px solid black';
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        cell4.id = 'cell' + 3; 
        cell4.style.border = '1px solid black';
        cell4.style.height ='80px'
        cell1.innerHTML  = days[i]; 
        cell2.innerHTML  = max[i]; 
        cell3.innerHTML  =  average[i]; 
        cell4.innerHTML  = "<div class='animWD'>" + wd[i] + "</div>" + "<br />" + windS[i];  /* i wann animate wd[i] elements*/
      }

  }

 createTable();
 function anim(){ $(".animWD").toggle("slow"); }
 let int =  setInterval(anim, 1000);
```

Every 1000 milliseconds show or hide the data with class animWD.